# Git commit returns nothing to commit

Tags: git

What do I do when git commit returns `On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean`?
I had an existing git repository initialized, I wiped with using rm -rf .git then I type git init.
Could that be the reason why my files would not commit?

Comment: Did you `git add` your files? What does `git status` print?

Comment: what does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: `rm -rf .git` removed the entire repository proper, leaving you with just the working tree. The subsequent `git init` created a new, *empty* repository, with nothing at all in it, leaving the working tree undisturbed. You must run `git add` to copy any files you wish committed into the new repository's *index* aka *staging area*, since `git commit` builds the new commit *from* the index (not from the working tree).

Comment: Note that I distinguish here between the "repository proper" (the stuff in `.git`) and the *working tree* (where you see and work on files). The stuff inside a Git repository is not modifiable and not usable as ordinary files, so we *check out* a commit, using `git checkout` or `git switch`, to *extract* those files into the working tree. A standard repository provides a working tree area for you to work in, but that working tree isn't part of the repository itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you wiped using `rm -rf .git`, that folder becomes normal folder. You have performed git init and now before comiting you need to add the untracked files into indexed/staged for that do the following.

```
git init
git add .  # To add entire files in the folder to staged area
```

or

```
git add <specific filename> # to add specific file into staged area
git status                  # To check the list of files ready for commit
git commit                  # Now you'll be able to commit
```